# How to create a loop to see whether desired row with inputs is filled out correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

how my JSON looks like:

```
{
"main_object": {
"id": "5",
"getExerciseTitle": "TestFor",
"language": "nl_NL",
"application": "lettergrepen",
"main_object": {
  "title": "TestFor",
  "language": "nl_NL",
  "exercises": [
    {
      "word": "test",
      "syllables": [
        "test01",
        "test02",
        "test03",
        ""
      ]
    },
    {
      "word": "tesst",
      "syllables": [
        "test11",
        "test12",
        "",
        ""
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"dataType": "json"
}
}
```

how my function looks like:

```
function prepareCheck() {
 $.getJSON('json_files/jsonData_' + ID + '.json', function(json) {
              $(document).on('input', '.syl-input', function() {
var $wordContainer = $(this).closest('.exerciseWord'),
wordIndex = $('.exerciseWord').index($wordContainer);

var valuesArray = $wordContainer.find('.syl-input').map(function() {
return this.value
}).get()

  var syllablesArray = json.main_object.main_object.exercises[wordIndex].syllables;
console.log(syllablesArray);
  var isValid = valuesArray.every(function(val, i) {
 return syllablesArray[i] === val;
 });
$wordContainer.toggleClass('valid', isValid)
   });
 });
}
 });
 }
```

### What I am trying to achieve, but no idea how:

I would like to create a loop that will go through the syllables for each desired `word`. `word` "test" has 3 `syllables` and on my front-end it displays 3 input fields for that desired `word` that should be filled out correctly. However, how can I loop through my `syllables` and create that whenever all the `syllables` of the desired `word` are filled out, it should make them all turn into green buttons. The desired `syllables` should only turn into green buttons when I fill out the `syllables` correctly. So for my first `word` the 3 input fields should jump to green buttons when I successfully insert  "test01", "test02", "test03" and for my second `word` it should turn the 2 input fields into green buttons when I fill those out correctly. They should however remain input fields as long as not all the desired input fields of a certain `word` are filled out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Following uses [`Array#every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to loop through an array of the values for inputs associated with each word and match to data for that word

Also uses jQuery [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) of the parent word container to get the proper data to compare to

```js
$(document).on('input', '.syl', function() {
  var $wordContainer = $(this).closest('.word'),
    wordIndex = $('.word').index($wordContainer);
    
  var valuesArray = $wordContainer.find('.syl').map(function() {
    return this.value
  }).get()

  var syllablesArray = data.main_object.main_object.exercises[wordIndex].syllables

  var isValid = valuesArray.every(function(val, i) {
    return syllablesArray[i] === val;
  });

  $wordContainer.toggleClass('valid', isValid)
})
```

```css
.word.valid .syl {
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="word">
  <input class="syl" placeholder="Enter test01" /><br>
  <input class="syl" value="test02" /><br>
  <input class="syl" value="test03" />

</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="word">
  <input class="syl" placeholder="Enter tesst11" /><br>
  <input class="syl" value="tesst12" />
</div>

<script>
  var data = {
    "main_object": {
      "id": "5",
      "getExerciseTitle": "TestFor",
      "language": "nl_NL",
      "application": "lettergrepen",
      "main_object": {
        "title": "TestFor",
        "language": "nl_NL",
        "exercises": [{
            "word": "test",
            "syllables": [
              "test01",
              "test02",
              "test03",
              ""
            ]
          },
          {
            "word": "tesst",
            "syllables": [
              "tesst11",
              "tesst12",
              "",
              ""
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "dataType": "json"
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: a few questions: first one is: is this possible without the library u provided? The library kind of bumps into other functionality and therefore I rather not use it. second of all, basically ur saying with ur code, I don't need to really use the variables to go into my json and then compare what I write down in my input field with a variable that loops through the syllables in my json? last question: is it possible to make them green buttons when they are correct? instead of just adding a yellow background color to the input field? (with bootstrap btn btn-success)

Comment: and another quick question tho: for what piece of code should urs be replaced then?

Comment: The only library i used is jQuery which you are already using. As for the variables question that doesn't make sense. As for the buttons do whatever you want. You didn't provide any html so not sure what you need to modify but you would do it based on `isValid`. I simply toggled a class so you can do the same on whatever elements you need

Comment: about the library, you were correct. I do somehow use it lol.. just a quick sidenote (and hoping you could clarify), why can't I access the json data? It throws the error cannot read property of undefined, but with urs in the snippet it works fine

Comment: Did you store that data anywhere?

Comment: yes, in my JSON files. I however do access the JSON files. I could edit the post so you can see what I have right now? it's only the function that I changed, so it won't go too off topic either

Comment: I mean in the page after you create the elements

Comment: No... I thought the variable accessed the JSON file (since It is inside the  $.getJSON('json_files/jsonData_' + ID + '.json', function(json) {...} part

Comment: But the event occurs much later and you need to be able to access that data then.

Comment: made a little edit so you can see what I have right now, the class word and the class syl for you are class exerciseWord and syl-input for mine.

Comment: Create a runnable demo that includes bootstrap if that is what you are using

Comment: Nope, can't seem to make a runnable demo without having tons of other errors (using some mini libraries that aren't online exactly), ur code did work, but just not with mine. still appreciate the effort tho